# Get element out of list in scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I have customer information list like this;

(Mike USA married John UK single Kate Germany married Tom USA single ...)

I want to define scheme function called **find** to retrieve customer information for given name.

Ex:- find Kate -> (Germany married)

thanx in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list always has a correct structure, it's a simple matter of iterating over it, advancing three items at a time:

```
(define (find data name)
  (cond ((null? data) #f)
        ((equal? (car data) name)
         (list (cadr data) (caddr data)))
        (else (find (cdddr data) name))))
```

For example:

```
(define data
  '(Mike USA married John UK single Kate Germany married Tom USA single))

(find data 'Kate)
=> '(Germany married)

(find data 'Bob)
=> #f
```